# laravel4, why can not return the view with setting the route to post method?

Tags: php, laravel-4

the code of route:

```
//Route::get('/user/login', 'UserController@login');
Route::post('/user/login', 'UserController@login');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

the code of UserController:

```
public function login()
{
    return View::make('user.login');
}

public function create()
{
    return View::make('user.register');
}
```

I add an custom method in the resource controller, and i want it return the login view if the route is /user/login. But I have a question why login view is not displayed if i set route to post method? When i use get method, the login view can be displayed.

Comment: The routes are red top-bottom. When you are using resource controllers you can have a store method, to handle the post request. In my opinion resource controllers aren't the best way to handle user auth actions, they exist for other purposes.

Comment: @Dimitris Kontoulis yea. I use the store method to save user into the database. So in the resource controller, there can be only 1 method to handle the post request, but more than 1 method can handle get method?

Comment: Exactly that's why I told you it is not the best method for auth. You can handle single entities with resource controllers, like articles or photos.

Comment: How do you access that `post` url?

Comment: You don't "access" a post url, you are using a request with post method, like when you are submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a resource controller, you should be using a normal controller.

**Routes.php**

```
<?php
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

and **UserController.php**

```
<?php
    function getLogin() {
        return View::make('login');
    }
    function postLogin() {
        // handle post login stuff
    }
```